# How to Dynamically Add to the TSQL Where Clause in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to dynamically add conditions to the TSQL Where clause?

I'm trying to avoid selecting between two complete Select statements.  The following is very similar, but less complicated, than my actual code.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  ShipDate >= @FirstDayOfMonth
AND    ShipDate <  @LastDayOfMonth
AND    OrderType = 1
AND    NOT OrderCode LIKE '%3'
AND    NOT OrderCode LIKE '%4';
```

I would like to be able to add or remove the last two conditions depending on the value of a stored procedure parameter.

i.e.: if @ExcludePhoneOrders = False , don't use the last two Where clause conditions.

Comment: Solution: `WHERE ShipDate >= @FirstDayOfMonth` `AND ShipDate < @LastDayOfMonth` `AND OrderType = 1` `AND (@ExcludePhoneOrders=False` `OR ( (NOT OrderCode LIKE '%3')` `AND (NOT OrderCode LIKE '%4') ) );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you meant to include or exclude, but here is a stab at it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  ShipDate >= @FirstDayOfMonth
AND    ShipDate <  @LastDayOfMonth
AND    OrderType = 1
AND    (@ExcludePhoneOrders = False OR (NOT OrderCode LIKE '%3' AND NOT OrderCode LIKE '%4'));
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great by changing to `@ExcludePhoneOrders = False OR ...`. Do you know why it works?

Comment: Either the logic on the left or right must be true to display the rows.  If @ExcludePhoneOrders = False, then it doesn't need to even bother parsing the right hand side of the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

It should look something like this...
If the datatype I used is not right, you should change them.
But the main concept should remain the same.
Let me know how it goes.

```
Create proc GetOrders
   ....,
   @FirstDayOfMonth int,
   @LastDayOfMonth int,
   ....
AS
DECLARE @SQL varchar(1000)
DECLARE @PARAMS nvarchar(100);

set @SQL='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   MyTable WHERE  ShipDate >= @FirstDay_OfMonth AND    ShipDate <  @LastDay_OfMonth AND    OrderType = 1';

if(@ExcludePhoneOrders = 1)
begin
  set @SQL=@SQL + ' AND NOT OrderCode LIKE ''%3'' AND NOT OrderCode LIKE ''%4'''
end

SET @PARAMS = '@FirstDayOfMonth int, @LastDayOfMonth int'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @PARAMS, @FirstDay_OfMonth = @FirstDayOfMonth, @LastDay_OfMonth=@LastDayOfMonth
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Projapati. That's a good solution. I was trying to keep the code as readable as possible, so I went with Korey's suggestion. Your code is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You could dump the query to a varchar, then use an if statement to optionally append the extra where clause info, then pass the whole thing to sp_executesql.

Comment: That would have been my last resort if there was no other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  ShipDate >= @FirstDayOfMonth
AND    ShipDate <  @LastDayOfMonth
AND    OrderType = 1
AND (
    (@ExcludePhoneOrders <> False AND NOT OrderCode LIKE '%3' AND NOT OrderCode LIKE '%4')
    OR
    @ExcludePhoneOrders = False 
)
```

You need consider handle NULL value if parameter can be NULL

Comment: This also worked. I used the code from Korey as it was one line less. Thanks for your help. I must now try to understand how SQL processes that section of code; as in why it work. I handle NULL with a default parameter.