# Conditional WHERE Clauses In A Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This question may boil down to something simpler, but I am still curious as to how close SQL Server / TSQL can get to conditional `WHERE` clauses (and reasoning behind why they don't exist would also be interesting).

I have a stored procedure that, for a few parameters, takes in an enumeration array (which has been accordingly translated to a user-defined table type which essentially mocks an int array). For reference the data type is as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE myIntArray AS TABLE (
    val INT
);
```

My stored procedure is along the following lines (altered to be more simplistic):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
    @homeID INT,
    @name VARCHAR(500),
    @hometype_enum myIntArray READONLY,
    @country_enum myIntArray READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM my_table
    WHERE name=@name
END
GO
```

What I am wanting to do is additionally filter the results of my query based upon the values of the enum arrays that were passed in as INT tables, IFF they even have values passed in (it is possible the tables might be empty). The pseudo code would look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE name = @name
IF((SELECT COUNT(val) FROM @hometype_enum) > 0)
BEGIN
    AND hometype IN (SELECT val FROM hometype_enum)
END
IF((SELECT COUNT(val) FROM @country_enum ) > 0)
BEGIN
    AND country IN (SELECT val FROM country_enum )
END
```

The two enums are independent of each other, so it's possible a search could be made and be filtered on no enum (both tables empty), either-or, or both enums.

My actual query involves multiple columns, tables, and unions (ugly, I know), so it's not as nice as just being able to copy/paste a 3-line `SELECT` for each scenario. I am currently using some pretty ugly temp table logic that I'll spare the reader's eyes from at the moment.

Aside from figuring out my particular problem, my main question is: does SQL Server support conditional `WHERE` clause statements (I am convinced it does not from my research)? Why is this (architectural, time complexity, space complexity issues)? Are there any more-or-less terse ways to go about emulating a conditional clause, such as [taking advantage of conditional short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431472/how-to-dynamically-add-to-the-tsql-where-clause-in-a-stored-procedure)?

Thank you all for your insights. Another day of learning!

Comment: You can do "condition where" clauses using dynamic SQL.  This has the advantage of re-compiling the query, so the execution plan can make optimal use of indexes.  (Some might think that recompilation is not an advantage.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the best way to handle this kind of conditional where clause would be to use dynamic-sql ..... Something like....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
    @homeID INT,
    @name VARCHAR(500),
    @hometype_enum myIntArray READONLY,
    @country_enum myIntArray READONLY
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON

 Declare @Sql NVarchar(MAX);

 SET @Sql = N' SELECT * FROM my_table '
          + N' WHERE name = @name '
           + CASE WHEN EXISTS (Select * FROM @hometype_enum)
             THEN N' AND hometype IN (SELECT val FROM hometype_enum) ' ELSE N' ' END
           + CASE WHEN EXISTS (Select * FROM @country_enum)
             THEN N' AND country IN (SELECT val FROM country_enum ) ' ELSE N' ' END

  Exec sp_executesql @Sql
                    ,N'@homeID INT , @name VARCHAR(500),
                      @hometype_enum myIntArray, @country_enum myIntArray'
                    ,@homeID
                    ,@name
                    ,@hometype_enum
                    ,@country_enum

END
GO
```

Using `sp_executesql` will allow sql server to store parameterised execution plans for the same stored procedure. It is different execution plans for different sets/combinations of a parameters for the same stored procedure for optimal performance.

Comment: Out of curiosity: assuming `myProc` might need to be granted EXECUTE permissions for certain db users, might this create any problems when calling `sp_executesql`?

Comment: @mattkgross a very good question indeed, Actually in case of `sp_executesql` just giving users `Execute` permissions on the sp will not be enough, the users will need permission on the underlying `Tables` directly, this is one drawback of this approach.

Comment: @M.Ali he can use `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` for his SP or `EXECUTE AS ...` and then `REVERT;`. Is this a good enough approach?

Answer (score 4):

The below one works fine too. There is no need for dynamic-sql. The MS SQL will handle it without issues (with good performance).

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
    @homeID INT,
    @name VARCHAR(500),
    @hometype_enum myIntArray READONLY,
    @country_enum myIntArray READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM my_table
    WHERE name=@name
      AND ( ( SELECT count(val)  FROM @hometype_enum ) = 0 
            OR   hometype IN (SELECT val FROM @hometype_enum) )
      AND ( ( SELECT count(val)  FROM @country_enum ) = 0 
            OR   country IN (SELECT val FROM @country_enum) )

END
GO
```

The `OR` will make the job for you. When first part : `SELECT count(val)  FROM @hometype_enum ) = 0` will return true then the second one will not be executed at all - no error from empty `IN` clause. When the first part will return some value grater than 0 then the second one will be evaluated correctly.

Comment: Make sure to read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html), specifically about what `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` does.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Is it required for all versions or only old ones? In Oracle there is some feature called Adaptive Cursor Sharing. Isn't there anything similar to it in MSSQL?

Comment: Are you talking about versions of SQL Server? As far as I know, latest version of SQL Server still has a feature called ["parameter sniffing"](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options) and execution plan caching, which is usually useful, but for this kind of queries is often harmful. [In SQL Server 2016 Parameter Sniffing can be controlled at database level](http://dinesql.blogspot.com.au/2016/04/sql-server-2016-parameter-sniffing-can.html). I don't know Oracle and I don't know what its "Adaptive Cursor Sharing" does.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov It seems the parameter sniffing works during compilation only. The Adaptive Cursor Sharing learns on fly that some parameters are harmful. DBMS "notes" it and next time knows to treat it in a different way (I simplified it a little bit).I am surprised that SQL Server doesn't have such feature as my users make such queries on SQL/Oracle and  I haven't noticed any problems with it so far. Maybe I am lucky. Thanks Vladimir for your comment. I will keep it my mind.